# Can anyone explain how the lambda function works as a key in the sorted method?

Tags: python

I know that the sorted method here sorts my list in ascending order but how does this lambda function changes the functionality of my code?

```
list = [ (1,4), (0,8), (5,6), (7,10)]

list_sorted = sorted(list, key = lambda list: list[1], reverse = False)

print("Sorted:", list_sorted)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `key` parameter of the `sorted` function modifies the sorting. Instead of comparing based on the values, it'll compare based off the value returned by the `key` function. In this case, `key` returns the second element of the tuple, so the list will be sorted based off the second element of the tuple, and not the first like tuples normally are.

See [the official docs for more info](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions).

(to be pedantic tuples aren't sorted by the first element, they're sorted lexicographically starting from the first element)

Comment: Now i got that. Thanks for telling in a brief and simple way.

Answer (score 0):

Each element of the iterable is passed to the sorting function, then you're extracting and comparing on the second elements of each item as the key

Answer (score 0):

Short remark: Please don't call your list `list`. It overrides the python list method an can lead to some confusing error messages

You can apply the lambda function by using `map` to see what it does:

```
In [9]: your_list = [ (1,4), (0,8), (5,6), (7,10) ]                                                                                                                                                        

In [11]: list(map(lambda x: x[1], your_list))                                                                                                                                                              
Out[11]: [4, 8, 6, 10]
```

So for each tuple inside your list it takes the second elements (counting starts at 0). When you call `sorted` it then sorts this elements reorders the tuples accordingly.

In your cases the output of the lambda is already sorted correctly, so the `sorted` functions does not need to reorder anything

```
In [13]: sorted(your_list, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse = False)                                                                                                                                          
Out[13]: [(1, 4), (5, 6), (0, 8), (7, 10)]
```

If you had initialized `your_list` in a different order you would still get the same result

```
In [14]: your_list = [ (0,8), (1,4), (7,10), (5,6) ]                                                                                                                                                       

In [15]: sorted(your_list, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse = False)                                                                                                                                          
Out[15]: [(1, 4), (5, 6), (0, 8), (7, 10)]
```

Comment: i got that! Thanks mate :)